# Problems when trying to register information in the HTML form to my database with XAMPP

Tags: javascript, logic

I have spent several days trying to connect my MySQL database in XAMPP with my html form, and I get error 405 Y Unexpected end of JSON input. Supposedly I had to configure the XAMPP web server to accept the POST method, and still I keep getting the same 405 error, I have been using AI to help me solve but as much as I follow the instructions to solve the problems with this method I do not are solved:

HTML:

```html
<form id="register-form" action="guardar_registro.php" method="POST">
<form id="register-form" action="save_registro.php" method="POST">
```

JavaScript:

```js
fetch('/flags 4/save_registro.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      username: username,
      email: email,
      password: password
    })
  })
```

and PHP:

```php
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've suggested an edit that fixes the code formatting. Is that all of your PHP? It looks like some is missing, like the part that does the JSON parsing. Have you checked to see if the POST body is getting mangled into `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? I think that's the default

Comment: This is my PHP code with more details: <?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "mi_base_de_datos";                                          header('Content-Type: application/json');...
   ... echo json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

Comment: Maybe try adding `headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }` to the `fetch`?